# I'm getting an error while including another file in the settings gradle file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am trying to include honeywell file in android settings gradle file but I am getting error.

settings.gradle file down below

```
include ':app'
include ':honeywell'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

My file directory is as in the picture I added below.

[image]

The error I get when I build is as in the picture below.

[image]

Flutter package i use

- https://pub.dev/packages/honeywell_scanner

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code like below in your app gradle file.

`implementation project(path: ':<Project-name>')`

Comment: can u be more specific